# Click through div and fade out on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navbar on the top of the page, and when certain events run, I have a header that pops up for about 3 seconds. During this time you cannot click on the underlying nav links.

```
.alert-header{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I tried doing a css `transition`, but pointer events are set to none. So I tried with jquery (assuming pointer events only affect css):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.alert-header', function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.2}, 'fast');
}).on('mouseleave', '.alert-header', function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast');
});
```

So, after doing that and testing it, I get the same result as with doing a css transition.

Is there a way where I can fade out the header to `0.2` opacity when the mouse moves over it, and be able to click on the underlying links?

Comment: what if on hover you change `pointer-events: all !important`?

Comment: Then I won't be able to click through it...

Comment: Then I guess I am a little confused on your structure and how you are using pointer events

Comment: Assuming, that all nav bar links have same CLASS (you can add one class for special use in JS), AND you have 2 functions to SHOW and HIDE of the popup, simply add `$( ".yourclass" ).prop( "disabled", true );` on show of alert and `$( ".yourclass" ).prop( "disabled", false );` on hide function of that alert.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured out a way. First in the css I turn off pointer events for the div I want to click through:

```
.alert-header{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Next I test the `Y` position of the mouse when it moves cursor and when the header is visible, if the `Y` position is less than the height of the header I make it fade, otherwise I fade it back to opaque.

```
var fadeRunning = false;
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    var header = $('.alert-header');
    if(header.is(':visible')){
        var mouseY = e.pageY;
        var height = header.outerHeight();
        if(mouseY <= height && !fadeRunning){
            fadeRunning = true;
            header.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 'fast', function(){fadeRunning=false});
        }else{
            if(!fadeRunning){
                fadeRunning = true;
                header.animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast', function(){fadeRunning=false});
            }
        }
    }else{
        header.css({opacity: 1});
    }
});
```